# Graficos 3D juntos no python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gráfico, python-requests, ipython-notebook

Possuo esses dois graficos:

[image: grafico 1]

[image: grafico 2]

Essas são as informações para gerar eles:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *
init_printing(pretty_print=true)
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

tdh1 = np.arange(0,1,0.05)
tdhgraf= np.arange(0,24,1.2)
rmax1 = 240
Ci1= 54.5
Ks1= 12
rec1= np.arange(0,2.5,0.5)
y = dict()

  resolucoes = list()
for rec in rec1:
  print("rec=",rec)
  y[rec] = list()
  for tdh in tdh1:
    print(f"\ttdh={tdh:.2f}")
    eqn1=Eq(tdh,(((rec*Cx1+Ci1)/(rec+1))-Cx1) / (rmax1*Cx1/(Cx1+Ks1)))
    solucao = solve(eqn1)[1]
    resolucoes.append(Eq(Cx1, solucao))
    print("\t\t",Eq(Cx1, solucao))
    y[rec].append(float(solucao))

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
# y1= ([54.5, 40.6059958386229,  29.0291097596484,  20.4618770789121,  14.7722373813368,  11.1507521408923, 8.80192534648665,
#         7.2098049424219,  6.07923983302962 ,  5.24278806144571, 4.60231761846384, 4.09780082567888, 3.69093376342374, 3.35631917289634, 3.07653894102323, 2.83928981686097, 2.63565508063512, 2.45902540440416, 2.30440398673506, 2.16794660276316])

# y2=([54.5,36.4448984186373,22.9708572951992,14.7722373813368,10.2576005706936,7.67803571119502,6.07923983302962,5.01106920644036,4.25356004636753,3.69093376342374,3.25765902617313,2.91425339569165,2.63565508063512,2.405249626108,2.2116141829834,2.04664952977099,1.90445983234838,1.78065463494135,1.67189923733046,1.57561652374871])

for yrec in y:
  plt.plot(tdhgraf, y[yrec], label=f'rec {yrec:.2f}')

plt.xlabel('TDH (h)')
plt.ylabel('N (saída) (mg/L)')

plt.title("Consumo de Nitrogênio")

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

AQUI FORMA O GRAFICO 1

da mesma forma:

```
tdh2 = np.arange(0,1,0.05)
tdhgraf= np.arange(0,24,1.2)
rmax2 = 3000
Ci2= 512
Ks2= 234
rec2= np.arange(0,2.5,0.5)
y = dict()

resolucoes = list()
for rec in rec1:
  print("rec=",rec)
  y[rec] = list()
  for tdh in tdh2:
    print(f"\ttdh={tdh:.2f}")
    eqn2=Eq(tdh,(((rec*Cx2+Ci2)/(rec+1))-Cx2) / (rmax2*Cx2/(Cx2+Ks2)))
    solucao = solve(eqn2)[1]
    resolucoes.append(Eq(Cx2, solucao))
    print("\t\t",Eq(Cx2, solucao))
    y[rec].append(float(solucao))  

for yrec in y:
  plt.plot(tdhgraf, y[yrec], label=f'rec {yrec:.2f}')

plt.xlabel('TDH (h)')
plt.ylabel('C (saída) (mg/L)')

plt.title("consumodecarbono")

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

AQUI FORMA O GRAFICO 2

Gostaria de uma ajuda para formar tipo um grafico 3D mostrando todas as curvas (dos dois graficos) em apenas um novo grafico tipo desse exemplo aqui:

[image: grafico 3]

essa é descrição da formação desse gráfico:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)


df = pd.read_excel('EDS 7.xlsx', header=None, usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F','G','H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'])
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [14.5,10]
# put 0s on the y-axis, and put the y axis on the z-axis
ax.plot(xs=df['A'], ys=df['B'], zs=df['C'], zdir='z', label='ys=0, zdir=z', color='blue')
ax.plot(xs=df['D'], ys=df['E'], zs=df['F'], zdir='z', label='ys=0, zdir=z', color='red')
ax.plot(xs=df['G'], ys=df['H'], zs=df['I'], zdir='z', label='ys=0, zdir=z', color='green')
ax.plot(xs=df['J'], ys=df['K'], zs=df['L'], zdir='z', label='ys=0, zdir=z', color='orange')
plt.xlim([0.0, 4.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 4.0])
ax.set_zlim(0,1200)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=16)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=16)
#plt.xticks(np.arange(0.0,1.4,0.1).round(decimals=1))
#plt.yticks(np.arange(-0.8,1.3,0.2).round(decimals=1))
ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
ax.w_zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
ax.xaxis._axinfo["grid"]['linestyle'] = '--'
ax.xaxis._axinfo["grid"]['color'] = 'silver'
ax.yaxis._axinfo["grid"]['linestyle'] = '--'
ax.yaxis._axinfo["grid"]['color'] = 'silver'
ax.zaxis._axinfo["grid"]['linestyle'] = '--'
ax.zaxis._axinfo["grid"]['color'] = 'silver'
ax.tick_params(axis='z', pad=10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho acesso aos seus dados (por exemplo, no código que você compartilhou, sua variável `tdhgraf` não está definida), então vou dar um exemplo de **como transpor um gráfico 2D para 3D** usando dados arbitrários.

Aqui defino os dados que serão plotados - uma série de valores X e 4 séries de valores Y:

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

ys1 = xs ** 2
ys2 = ys1 + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=10)
ys3 = ys1 + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=20)
ys4 = ys1 + np.random.normal(loc=-10, scale=10)
```

Aqui o plot do gráfico 2D - apenas itero sobre as séries `ys` e as suas respectivas cores (que defini diretamente no código) e peço para plotá-las com `plt.plot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ys = [ys1, ys2, ys3, ys4]
colors = 'orange green red blue'.split()

for y, color in zip(ys, colors):
    plt.plot(xs, y, c=color)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para transformarmos o gráfico 2D para 3D, há 3 coisas que precisam ser feitas:

- **Criar uma terceira série de valores** - a série `zs` define a posição de cada curva na terceira dimensão (nesse caso, a posição é fixa);
- **Criar um objeto `Axes3D`** - diferente do caso 2D, eu preciso explicitamente criar um objeto desse tipo para plotar em 3 dimensões. Na hora de plotar, usamos o seu método `ax.plot` no lugar de `plt.plot`;
- **Reorientar os eixos** - Por padrão, o eixo Z de um gráfico 3D aponta para cima. Mas a informação que queremos que apareça na vertical são as séries de valores Y. Para não precisarmos redefinir as séries de `ys` e os valores de `zs`, usamos o argumento `zdir='y'` na hora de plotar para que essa mudança da orientação dos eixos seja feita automaticamente.

Aqui o código:

```
# Criando série de zs
zs = np.linspace(0, len(ys)-1, len(ys))

# Criando o Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Plotando em 3D, com reorientação de eixos
for y, z, color in zip(ys, zs, colors):
    ax.plot(xs, y, z, c=color, zdir='y')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: agradeço seu retorno! muito obrigado! Eu tentei aplicar essa linguagem para os meus dados e não estou conseguindo entender muito bem. Vou editar na publicação para aparecer todos os meus valores de entrada e se você conseguiria aplicar meus dados em um gráfico 3d. Gostaria que nesse mesmo grafico 3d aparecessem tanto as curvas do grafico 1 quanto do grafico 2. Obrigado!